# MAAS node refuses IP address assigned to it by DHCP

Tags: server, juju, maas, dhcp

I am trying to configure MAAS and Juju in a test environment. My MAAS region and cluster controllers are on a single machine with two NICs. eth1 is connected to a LAN with internet access; IP is 192.168.181.32. eth0 is a private network. I have configured it to use 192.168.212.0/24.

MAAS is configured to manage DHCP and DNS on eth0. I have added 3 nodes to the cluster, and all report status as Ready. Everything goes sour when I try to bootstrap Juju, though:

```
> juju bootstrap --upload-tools
WARNING ignoring environments.yaml: using bootstrap config in file "/home/dannyb/.juju/environments/maas.jenv"
uploading tools for series [trusty precise]
Launching instance
WARNING picked arbitrary tools &{"1.18.4.1-trusty-amd64" "http://192.168.212.1:80/MAAS/api/1.0/files/?key=2bbe30ca-560c-11e4-9ea3-0800272d5f95&op=get_by_key" "1f9d6f5eda1ebb85106259be5ba91aa700fe7c772437d8b38f3adf231d09b4de" %!q(int64=7358699)}
 - /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-da4858c2-5603-11e4-b417-0800272d5f95/
Waiting for address
Attempting to connect to cloud2.maas.allworx.com:22
Attempting to connect to 192.168.212.8:22
```

So far so good. The **cloud2** node starts up and connects to PXE, but then I start getting:

```
IP-Config: eth0 hardware address 08:00:27:1d:ea:91 mtu 1500 DHCP RARP
hostname cloud2 hostname cloud2 hostname cloud2 hostname cloud2 IP-Config: no response after 2 secs - giving up
IP-Config: eth0 hardware address 08:00:27:1d:ea:91 mtu 1500 DHCP RARP
hostname cloud2 hostname cloud2 hostname cloud2 hostname cloud2 IP-Config: no response after 3 secs - giving up

etc...
```

The syslog on my cluster controller shows:

```
Oct 17 11:58:20 maas-master dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 08:00:27:1d:ea:91 via eth0
Oct 17 11:58:20 maas-master dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.212.8 to 08:00:27:1d:ea:91 via eth0
Oct 17 11:58:22 maas-master dhcpd: Dynamic and static leases present for 192.168.212.8.
Oct 17 11:58:22 maas-master dhcpd: Remove host declaration 192.168.212.8 or remove 192.168.212.8
Oct 17 11:58:22 maas-master dhcpd: from the dynamic address pool for 192.168.212.0/24
Oct 17 11:58:22 maas-master dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.212.8 (192.168.212.1) from 08:00:27:1d:ea:91 via eth0
Oct 17 11:58:22 maas-master dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.212.8 to 08:00:27:1d:ea:91 via eth0
Oct 17 11:58:42 maas-master dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 08:00:27:1d:ea:91 via eth0
Oct 17 11:58:42 maas-master dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.212.8 to 08:00:27:1d:ea:91 via eth0
Oct 17 11:58:42 maas-master dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.212.6 (192.168.212.3) from 08:00:27:1d:ea:91 via eth0: lease 192.168.212.6 unavailable.
Oct 17 11:58:42 maas-master dhcpd: DHCPNAK on 192.168.212.6 to 08:00:27:1d:ea:91 via eth0
Oct 17 11:58:43 maas-master dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 08:00:27:1d:ea:91 via eth0
Oct 17 11:58:43 maas-master dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.212.8 to 08:00:27:1d:ea:91 via eth0
Oct 17 11:58:43 maas-master dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.212.6 (192.168.212.3) from 08:00:27:1d:ea:91 via eth0: lease 192.168.212.6 unavailable.
Oct 17 11:58:43 maas-master dhcpd: DHCPNAK on 192.168.212.6 to 08:00:27:1d:ea:91 via eth0
```

It looks like the node gets the 192.168.212.8 address, and uses it to download the kernel and initrd, but once the kernel starts up and it initializes the eth0 interface on the node, it refuses to accept the 212.8 address, and insists on a 212.6 address, which the DHCP server doesn't want to give it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem similar to this, but not exactly the same.  I tracked it down to having set "Static IP low" and "Static IP high" for the network the cluster controller was using.  Once I cleared the fields, the problem went away and it booted correctly.  Or, more correctly, I went on to other problems.